# Sequence conversion

Tags: sequence

Could you please help me to understand this problem:

> Convert the input sequence of `N` `(1 ≤ N ≤ 20)` input numbers so that
>   the subsequences of the same numbers are replaced with the first
>   numbers of the subsequences. Each input number is in the range `[1, 2
>   000 000 000]`.
>
> For example, the input sequence `1 2 2 3 1 1 1 4 4` is converted into
>   `1 2 3 1 4`.
>
> **Input**: First, the number T of test cases is given. Each test case is
>   specified using two lines. The first one contains the number N and the
>   second one contains the numbers of the sequence.
>
> **Output**: The converted sequence. The result for each test case should
>   be printed in a separate line.

Comment: You just want to keep uniqe values? is that it?

Comment: ı don't understand the problem, maybe it is that

Comment: I suspect english is not your native language and the problem was given to you in english, I think what `so that the subsequences of the same numbers are replaced with the first numbers of the subsequences`, simple means, remove all duplicates and keep only one.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, the input sequence 1 2 2 3 1 1 1 4 4 is converted into 1 2 3 1 4.

It looks like the idea is to remove duplicate numbers that occur adjacent to each other when creating the output.

You can do that by just keeping a state variable recording what the previous value was.  When you get a new value, compare it to the state value.  If it's the same, skip.  If different, output it and update the state variable.  Remember to initialize the state variable to a value not found in the input stream (e.g. -1 should work in this case).

Comment: _Remember to initialize the state variable to a value not found in the input stream (e.g. -1 should work in this case_, or to the first element in the sequence? Which would not require any guess at all like `-1`. You will always output the first value, and start searching for duplicates from the second one on, that makes a lot more sense I think.

Comment: Assuming you can peek at the first element in the sequence.  That is not always the case when consuming a stream of data. Otherwise you have to handle the special case "this is the first element".  That works, but the code is simpler if there is a value that is known not to be found in the input sequence.

Comment: _if there is a value that is known not to be found in the input sequence_, so a generic case is not possible to solve with this approach +1 anyway because you indeed answered the question.

Comment: Well the OP's problem constrains input value to the range 0..N, so that's why I suggested it as the simplest solution.  In some languages (e.g. C#) you can use a nullable int, or in C you can use an extra boolean to indicate whether you are looking at the first element.